# iPhone 5s lag related to repeated nsnetworkd crashes

Tags: ios, network, crash

Something weird is happening with my iPhone 5s on iOS 7.1.1. For the past week, it's become very laggy, where if I try to interact with it via software, Bluetooth, or even the physical buttons, it will often freeze completely for 1-10 seconds before resuming as if nothing had happened. Some of my apps have also started to occasionally crash on launch. Restarting didn't help.

Looking at my crash reports, I see that `nsnetworkd` process has been crashing and restarting pretty much nonstop since a week ago:

[image]

And looking at my system log, it seems that the cause of this is an unrecognized selector:

```
Jun  5 17:17:19 Pleasant-Brick nsnetworkd[1828] <Error>: -[__NSCFNumber _sha1Hash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
Jun  5 17:17:19 Pleasant-Brick nsnetworkd[1828] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber _sha1Hash]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'
```

(Oddly enough, network functionality seems to be unaffected.)

What on earth is going on? My phone isn't jailbroken, so I don't see how the `nsnetworkd` process could have changed in any way. Could this be some sort of new iOS virus?

I'm going to try to reset my network settings and then restore from backup if that doesn't work, but I'm really curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: I've got an identical pile of crash logs here on my 5s running freshly-released 7.1.2.

Comment: For the record, I fixed the problem by backing up my device and restoring from scratch, but I still have no idea what caused it.

Comment: Did you file this as a bug with Apple?